# Wrapper resultlist will not appear at my visualforce page

Tags: list, wrapper-class

The resultlist of my wrapper will not appear at my visualforce page. The debug log shows me that something is in the resultlist, but nothing at my visualforce page.

```
public class Camp_Letter {

    Private Id CamId {get; set;}
    Public List<ResultWrapper> resultList   {get; set;}

    public Camp_Letter() {       
        cam_output();        
    }
    
    public class ResultWrapper {
        public String       CampMem_Firstname              {get; set;}
        public String       CampMem_Lastname               {get; set;}
        public String       Acc_BDM_Lastname               {get; set;}         
        public String       Acc_PostCode                   {get; set;}      
    }
    
    public void cam_output() {
        
        Map<String, List<ResultWrapper>> mapPostCodeToWrapper = new Map<String, List<ResultWrapper>>();
        Set<String> PostCode = new Set<String>(); 
        CamId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');     
        
        for(Campaignmember CamM:[SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Contact.Account.BillingPostalcode FROM Campaignmember WHERE CampaignId = '7013N000000CnefQAC' and Status = 'selected']) {            
            PostCode.add(CamM.Contact.Account.BillingPostalcode);
            ResultWrapper wrap              = new ResultWrapper();
            wrap.CampMem_Firstname          = CamM.FirstName;
            wrap.CampMem_Lastname           = CamM.Lastname;
            wrap.Acc_PostCode               = CamM.Contact.Account.BillingPostalCod
            
            if(!mapPostCodeToWrapper.containsKey(wrap.Unt_PLZ)) {
                mapPostCodeToWrapper.put(wrap.Acc_PostCode, new List<ResultWrapper>());
            }
         
            mapPostCodeToWrapper.get(wrap.Unt_PLZ).add(wrap);
            
        }
        List<ResultWrapper> resultList = new List <ResultWrapper>();
        for(PostCode_List__c PostCodeList:[SELECT Name, BDM__r.Lastname FROM PostCode_List__c WHERE Name IN :PostCode]) {
            String Acc_PostCode                         = (String)PostCode_List__c.get('Name'); 
            for(ResultWrapper combinedResult : mapPostCodeToWrapper.get(Acc_PostCode)) {
                combinedResult.Acc_BDM_Lastname     = (String)PostCode_List__c.getSObject('BDM__r').get('Lastname');
                resultList.add(combinedResult);
            }
         }
    }   
}


<apex:page Controller="Camp_Letter">
    <apex:form >   
        <apex:repeat value="{!resultlist}" var="w">
            {!w.CampMem_Lastname}        
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is you are redeclaring the resultList variable inside `cam_output()` method:

```java
public class Camp_Letter {

    public List<ResultWrapper> resultList   {get; set;}

    public void cam_output() {

        // you must not redeclare the resultList property here
        // List<ResultWrapper> resultList = new List <ResultWrapper>();
        
        // initialize the existing property
        resultList = new List <ResultWrapper>();
        
        // for(
            resultList.add(combinedResult);
    }
}
```

Additionally, It can also be solved with using this keyword, specifying to use outer class property instead of local: `this.resultList.add(combinedResult);`